# How to lazy load an iterator and store metadata for future iterations

Tags: rust

I have a large CSV on disk that I need to iterate over. The CSV is too large to fit into memory, so I need to iterate over it lazily. The `csv` crate does a good job of this already. The issue I have is that I need to restart iteration without completing previous iteration passes, and I need to support random look ups of previously seen data without iterating over the file again.

My plan was to use the `csv` crate's iterator to progress through the file. Every time I reach a record, I was going to record metadata (record number, byte offset, length) so that I could fetch that record again. I  could also use this metadata to restart iteration by reading directly from the file at the given byte offsets instead of creating a new `csv` iterator.

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to get the lifecycles right. I'm new to Rust, and I honestly can't even begin to write down what I'd like to do with the appropriate lifecycles. Given the little experience I have with Rust, it's probably easier if I write what I'd like to do in pseudo-code:

```
struct IndexRecord {
  byte_offset: u64,
  length: u64,
}

struct CSVHandler {
  csv_iterator: StringRecordIterator, // from csv crate
  iterator_done: bool,
  index: Vec<IndexRecord>,
}

impl CSVHandler {
  pub fun get_iterator(&mut self) -> Iterator<String> {
    return IndexIterator{ handler: self, index: 0 }
  }
}

struct IndexIterator {
  handler: CSVHandler,
  index: u64,
}

impl Iterator for IndexIterator {
  type Item = String

  fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item {
    if (self.handler.index.len() > self.index) {
      let entry = self.handler.index.get(self.index);
      let line = // read from disk using entry.byte_offset and entry.length
      self.index += 1;
      return line;
    }

    if (self.handler.iterator_done) {
      return None
    }

    match self.handler.csv_iterator.next() {
      None => {
        self.handler.iterator_done = true
        return None
      },
      Some(entry) => {
        self.handler.index.push(IndexRecord { byte_offset: entry.byte_offset, length: entry.length });
        self.index += 1;
        return entry.text();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your main issue is that you're trying to use a StringRecordsIter. You want to use a csv::Reader so that you can call seek on it: https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.seek

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I don't think that's the issue. If I want to call `seek`, then I need a valid position to seek to. In order to have a valid position to seek to, I need to record the positions that have already been encountered. In my current setup, this involves borrowing a mutable reference twice. One to access the csv::Reader, and one to access the index of encountered positions. (btw, thanks for the great library)

Comment: Oh, in that case, use the methods available to you on the `StringRecordsIter` type: https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.StringRecordsIter.html#method.reader_mut

Also, don't forget about the `StringRecordsIntoIter` type. That tends to be useful in circumstances like this as well. And it also has corresponding methods for accessing the underlying reader.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe you would like to convert a sequential interface of a Reader/Iterator into a random-access interface, and because the whole data doesn't fit into memory, can't load it all, and the idea is to create an index over that data, but still keep the data on disk and load it on demand.

The first part, index creation, could be:

```
let reader = ...;
let it = reader.records();
let positions: Vec<csv::Position> = it.map(|record| {
    record.position().unwrap().clone(); // TODO: check errors
}).collect();
```

It extracts csv::Position instead of your custom IndexRecord, because it will be needed for seek() in order to reuse the library for reading from disk.

Having this index you could implement your random access reader:

```
struct RandomAccessCSVReader {
    reader: csv::Reader,
    positions: Vec<csv::Position>,
}

impl RandomAccessCSVReader {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut reader = ...;
        let positions = Self::read_positions(&mut reader);

        Self { reader, positions }
    }

    fn read_positions(&mut csv::Reader) -> Vec<csv::Position> {
        reader.records().map(|record| {
            record.position().unwrap().clone(); // TODO: check errors
        }).collect()
    }

    pub fn read_at(&mut self, i: usize) -> Result<StringRecord> {
        let pos = self.positions[i]; // TODO: check for bounds

        // seek into the file
        self.reader.seek(pos)?;

        // read from that position
        let mut record = StringRecord::new();
        self.reader.read_record(&mut record)?;

        Ok(record)
    }
}
```

This is a draft, please do the proper error checking.

Comment: If the number of lines also might not fit into memory (e.g. 1 billion entries of `csv::Position` is 24 GiB on a 64-bit system, due to `csv::Position` storing 3 `usize`s), you might want to lazily load all positions using a `HashMap<usize, csv::Position>`, possibly starting from the nearest existing position when discovering a new one.